# What is the difference between ojdbc6.jar and ojdbc14.jar?

Tags: java, oracle, jboss, oracle11g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ojdbc14.jar vs. ojdbc6.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209647/ojdbc14-jar-vs-ojdbc6-jar)

What is the difference between **ojdbc6.jar** and **ojdbc14.jar**?

I am using **jBoss 5.1.0 GA** and **Oracle database 11g R2 XE** with **jdk1.7.0_02**.

Which jar file should I use?

Comment: dup here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209647/ojdbc14-jar-vs-ojdbc6-jar

Comment: yes, i already saw that, I ask this because i've seen some in forum they're using  ojdbc14.jar in Oracle 11g. because im using recently ojdbc14 in oracle 10g.

Comment: then y ask the question here when u know u should be using ojdbc14.jar in oracle 11g?

Comment: i'm not sure if the ojdbc14.jar will still applicable in oracle 11g. sorry for the question sir, im only noob for this. thanks anyway

Comment: no worries :) noobiness on stackoverflow is nothing new xD, so please dont apologize - its all part of the learning process

Comment: Can i have your own answer or explanation from my question above sir? I want to learn from you.

Comment: no need - Evgeniy Dorofeev's answer is perfectly correct, so i would not be adding anything new to the post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both jars will work, but ojdbc6.jar is better, it is for Java 6. Newer Java versions add features unavailable in older version, new things are marked with `Since` tag in javadoc, eg Java 7 `Connection.abort` is tagged with

```
Since: 1.7
```

if you call a method missing in the jar you will get java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Comment: Ahh ok, Thanks for taking effort for replying this sir Evgeniy.