# post date with jquery datepicker in jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp, jdbc

I've this index HTML file. it contains jquery widgets for date fields.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<style>
div.ui-datepicker {
    font-size: 10px;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
    <form name="main" action="Insert_Record.jsp" method="post">
        <table class="bordered">
            <tr>
                <td>Serial Number</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="SerID" id="SerID"></td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shipment ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid"></td>
                <td>Product NAME</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="desc" id="desc"></td>
                <td>Phoenix Pub Code</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="pubcode" id="pubcode"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product Type</td>
                <td><select name="ProdType" id="ProdType">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
                        <option value="Looseleaf - Update">Looseleaf - Update</option>
                        <option value="Pamphlet">Pamphlet</option>
                </select></td>
                <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date Request received</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="DateRec" name="DateRec"></td>
                <td colspan="2">Time Received</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="TimeRec" name="TimeRec"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Units</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Units" id="Units"></td>
                <td colspan="2">VWR Due Date</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="VWR" id="VWR"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>AE Due Date</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="AEDue" name="AEDue"></td>
                <td colspan="2">Assign by Date</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="AsByDate"
                    name="AsByDate"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" align="center"><input type="submit"
                    value="Add Screen" id="addscr" name="addscr" onclick="addscr()" />

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#DateRec").datepicker({
                dateFormat : "mm-dd-y"
            }).val();
        });
        $(function() {
            $("#VWR").datepicker({
                dateFormat : "mm-dd-y"
            }).val();
        });
        $(function() {
            $("#AEDue").datepicker({
                dateFormat : "mm-dd-y"
            }).val();
        });
        $(function() {
            $("#AsByDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat : "mm-dd-y"
            }).val();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and i'm trying to post the data from this file to `Insert_Record.jsp`.

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*,java.text.*" %>
<%@include file="DBCon.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
try{

SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd");
String a=request.getParameter("sid");
String b=request.getParameter("desc");
String c=request.getParameter("pubcode");
String d=request.getParameter("ProdType");
Date e=formater.parse(request.getParameter("DateRec"));
String f=request.getParameter("TimeRec");
String g=request.getParameter("Units");
Date h=formater.parse(request.getParameter("VWR"));
Date i=formater.parse(request.getParameter("AEDue"));
Date j=formater.parse(request.getParameter("AsByDate"));
String k=request.getParameter("SerID");
String sql="insert into Welcome_Page (SHIPMENT_ID_/_IDS, PRODUCT_CODE, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_TYPE, UNIT_COUNT, RECEIVED_DATE, RECEIVED_TIME, VWR_DUE_DATE, AE_DUE_DATE, ASSIGN_BY_DATE,SERIAL_NUMBER) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
//String sql="insert into Welcome_Page(SHIPMENT_ID_/_IDS, PRODUCT_CODE, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_TYPE, UNIT_COUNT, RECEIVED_DATE, RECEIVED_TIME, VWR_DUE_DATE, AE_DUE_DATE, ASSIGN_BY_DATE,SERIAL_NUMBER) values ("+a+", '"+c+"', "+b+", '"+d+"', "+g+", '"+e+"', '"+f+"', '"+h+"', '"+i+"', '"+j+"', "+k+")";
ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1,a);
ps.setString(2,c);
ps.setString(3,b);
ps.setString(4,d);
ps.setString(5,g);
ps.setDate(6,new java.sql.Date(e.getTime()));
ps.setString(7,f);
ps.setDate(8,new java.sql.Date(h.getTime()));
ps.setDate(9,new java.sql.Date(i.getTime()));
ps.setDate(10,new java.sql.Date(j.getTime()));
ps.setString(11,k);
ps.executeQuery();
con.commit();
 }
catch(Exception e){
    out.println(e);
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

and i've all the DB connection in `DBCon.jsp`

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        Connection con = null;
        ResultSet rs, rs1 = null;
        PreparedStatement ps, ps1 = null;
        Statement st, st1 = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "system","tiger");
            st1=con.createStatement();
            rs=st1.executeQuery("select * from Welcome_Page");
            out.println(rs);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

when i'm filling up the information and submitting it is throwing the below error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.Insert_005fRecord_jsp._jspService(Insert_005fRecord_jsp.java:89)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

here i'm unable to figure out where have i gone wrong and how to fix this.
I'm really confused.

I've added odbc14.jar and classes12.jar in my library.

Thanks

Comment: your error title is not relented to the error you have, any way what oracle version you use ?,and what JVM version you use?

Comment: Hi @Dunken I'm using oracle 10G, and java latest version

Answer (score 1):

The ojdbc14 is made for JDK1.4 and 1.5 as mentiond in [oracle 10g driver  download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html) 
to understand the diffrence and what to use i recommed  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209647/ojdbc14-jar-vs-ojdbc6-jar)