# Object deserialization failure in ojdbc14 to ojdbc6 upgrade

Tags: java, serialization, jdbc, oracle11g, ojdbc

Object deserialization is failing for BLOB datatype in our application, after upgrading jdbc driver for Oracle database.

In our application, we have been using the ojdbc14 for the last couple of years without any issues. However recently we have decided 
to upgrde it to the ojdbc6. After upgrading to this new version, we are getting the below mentioned error, when ever we try to
read(deserialize) BLOB objects from the database. These objects were serialized and saved in the databse with the old version of ojdbc(14).
Here we are trying to read them with the new version of ojdbc(6).

```
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: oracle.sql.DatumWithConnection; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 491462912477014233, local class serialVersionUID = -5786207790829127167
```

According to the error log, I feel like they have updated the "serialVersionUID" in the oracle.sql.DatumWithConnection class. 
So it is failed to deserialize it when the new version of ojdbc is available.

So my questions are

1. Is there a way that we can get rid of this issue without going back to the old version?
2. Is there any other similar type of issues that we should be aware of, after this upgrade?

## FULL ERROR STACK

```
15:33:14,460 INFO  [STDOUT] ERROR [http-10.10.10.117-8080-2] (CommonsLogger.java:38) - Exception occurred during processing request: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.write(JSONWriter.java:102)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:116)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.createJSONString(JSONResult.java:197)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:367)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:271)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.____._____.s2.interceptor.AuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:40)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.custom.spring.plugin.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWrit
15:33:14,460 INFO  [STDOUT] er.java:178)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.array(JSONWriter.java:481)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:158)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:231)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.type.SerializableToBlobType.fromBytes(SerializableToBlobType.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.type.SerializableToBlobType.get(SerializableToBlobType.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractLobType.nullSafeGet(AbstractLobType.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2096)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1380)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1308)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1206)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:580)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:1994)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:565)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1716)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:158)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:231)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: oracle.sql.DatumWithConnection; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 491462912477014233, local class serialVersionUID = -5786207790829127167
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:562)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1582)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1582)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:210)
    ... 111 more
```

## Java Object Serialized in the Database

```
package com._____.aixis.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import oracle.sql.BLOB;

import com._____._____.domain.interfaces.ICostFactorItem;
import com._____._____.domain.interfaces.ITariffTypeCategory;

@Entity
@Table(name="______Docs")
public class Document extends DomainDefault implements Serializable,ITariffTypeCategory , ICostFactorItem {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5425465600991463936L;

    private Integer id;
    private String documentName;
    private DocumentType  documentType;
    private String docComment;
    private BLOB blobDoc;
    private String extension;
    private MasterData service;
    private DocumentInvoiceType documentInvoiceType;

    public Document() {
        super();
    }

    public Document(String documentName, DocumentType documentType, String docComment, BLOB blobDoc, String extension,
            MasterData service, Employee employee, Date createdDate) {
        super();
        this.documentName = documentName;
        this.documentType = documentType;
        this.docComment = docComment;
        this.blobDoc = blobDoc;
        this.extension = extension;
        this.service = service;
        if(employee != null){
            this.setCreatedBy(employee.getAccount().getUsername());
            this.setCreatedByUser(employee);
        }
        this.setCreatedDate(createdDate);
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDocumentName() {
        return documentName;
    }

    public void setDocumentName(String doumentName) {
        this.documentName = doumentName;
    }

    public DocumentType getDocumentType() {
        return documentType;
    }

    public void setDocumentType(DocumentType documentType) {
        this.documentType = documentType;
    }

    public String getDocComment() {
        return docComment;
    }

    public void setDocComment(String docComment) {
        this.docComment = docComment;
    }

    public String getExtension() {
        return extension;
    }

    public void setExtension(String extension) {
        this.extension = extension;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getCommonName() {
        return this.documentName +"-[" + this.documentType+"]";
    }

    @Transient
    public String getItemName() {
        return this.documentName +"-[" + this.documentType+"]";
    }

    @Lob
    public BLOB getBlobDoc() {
        return blobDoc;
    }

    public void setBlobDoc(BLOB blobDoc) {
        this.blobDoc = blobDoc;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getModifiedDate() {
        return modifiedDate;
    }

    @Override
    public void setModifiedBy(String modifiedBy) {
       this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    @Override
    public void setModifiedDate(Date modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE },fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public MasterData getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(MasterData service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public DocumentInvoiceType getDocumentInvoiceType() {
        return documentInvoiceType;
    }

    public void setDocumentInvoiceType(DocumentInvoiceType documentInvoiceType) {
        this.documentInvoiceType = documentInvoiceType;
    }

    @Override
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public Person getCreatedByUser() {
        return createdByUser;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCreatedByUser(Person createdBy) {
        this.createdByUser = createdBy;
    }

    @Override
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public Person getModifiedByUser() {
        return modifiedByUser;
    }

    @Override
    public void setModifiedByUser(Person modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedByUser = modifiedBy;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

** If you are in a hurry, just download the customized ojdbc6.jar file and use it. You don't have to do anything else.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz2PT96Cb0tSRk5XNGU3TUdHS1U

Summary Of My Answer

1. First, decompile the below-mentioned classes.

   •  oracle.sql.DatumWithConnection.class

   •  oracle.sql.BLOB.class
2. Then add the old serialVersionUIDs into these classes.(Old version ids are available in the error log)
3. After that recompile the classes.
4. Finally, update the ojdbc6.jar with the new classes to get upgraded and customized ojdbc library. That's it.

---

If you want to build the JAR manually, then read and follow the below-mentioned instructions.

## How to Bulid the Customized JAR

1. First, decompile the below-mentioned classes in the ojdbc6.jar file.

   • oracle.sql.DatumWithConnection.class

   • oracle.sql.BLOB.class

   To decompile, you can use "Java Decompiler" at http://jd.benow.ca/

(These were the classes that were giving trouble, when reading a saved BLOB object from the database.)

2. Create a simple java project(File--> New--> JavaProject) in eclipse or use the [Simple project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz2PT96Cb0tSb1BTRlcwMWtmbDA)  I have created.

If you are creating a new project, add the decompiled java files with the proper packaging structure(oracle.sql). 
    Also you have to add ojdbc6.jar file to the build path of this project.

3. Then add the old serialVersionUIDs into these decompiled java files.
   (Additional changes are also required to compile these java files.Please refer the updated java files below)

   ```
    DatumWithConnection.java ->    private static final long serialVersionUID = 491462912477014233L;

    BLOB.java          ->  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2160152488501369185L;
   ```
4. After that, build the project and get the recompiled classes.
5. Finally update the ojdbc6.jar with the new classes to get upgraded and customized ojdbc library. That’s it

   5.1 Create a new folder with the name "Updated JAR".

   5.2 Copy ojdbc6.jar file into that folder.
       D:\JARS\Updated JAR\ojdbc.jar

   5.3 Under that folder create two new folders to build the package structure for class files (\oracle\sql)

   5.4 Add both class files into the "sql" folder.

   ```
    D:\JARS\Updated JAR\oracle\sql\DatumWithConnection.class

    D:\JARS\Updated JAR\oracle\sql\BLOB.class
   ```

   5.5 Open a new commandline and change directory(cd) to the location where the jar file is located.

   ```
   >cd D:\JARS\Updated JAR
   ```

   5.6 To update the jar file with the new class files, use the below mentioned commands in the command line.

   ```
   >jar uf ojdbc6.jar oracle\sql\DatumWithConnection.class

   >jar uf ojdbc6.jar oracle\sql\BLOB.class
   ```

   5.7 Now you have a customized ojdbc6.jar file which works with the BLOB objects which were serialized and saved with the ojdbc14.jar

---

Updated java classes.

DatumWithConnection.java

```
    package oracle.sql;


    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError;
    import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;
    import oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleDatumWithConnection;

    public abstract class DatumWithConnection
      extends Datum
      implements OracleDatumWithConnection
    {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 491462912477014233L;

    private oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection physicalConnection = null;

      oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection getPhysicalConnection()
      {
        if (this.physicalConnection == null) {
          try
          {
            this.physicalConnection = ((oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection)new OracleDriver().defaultConnection());
          }
          catch (SQLException localSQLException) {}
        }
        return this.physicalConnection;
      }

      public DatumWithConnection(byte[] paramArrayOfByte)
        throws SQLException
      {
        super(paramArrayOfByte);
      }

      public DatumWithConnection() {}

      public static void assertNotNull(Connection paramConnection)
        throws SQLException
      {
        if (paramConnection == null)
        {
          SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(null, 68, "Connection is null");
          localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
          throw localSQLException;
        }
      }

      public static void assertNotNull(TypeDescriptor paramTypeDescriptor)
        throws SQLException
      {
        if (paramTypeDescriptor == null)
        {
          SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(null, 61);
          localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
          throw localSQLException;
        }
      }

      public void setPhysicalConnectionOf(Connection paramConnection)
      {
        this.physicalConnection = ((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)paramConnection).physicalConnectionWithin();
      }

      public Connection getJavaSqlConnection()
        throws SQLException
      {
        return getPhysicalConnection().getWrapper();
      }

      public oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection getOracleConnection()
        throws SQLException
      {
        return getPhysicalConnection().getWrapper();
      }

      public oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection getInternalConnection()
        throws SQLException
      {
        return getPhysicalConnection();
      }

      /**
       * @deprecated
       */
      public oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection getConnection()
        throws SQLException
      {
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection localOracleConnection = null;
        try
        {
          localOracleConnection = (oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection)((oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection)this.physicalConnection).getWrapper();
        }
        catch (ClassCastException localClassCastException)
        {
          SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 103);
          localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
          throw localSQLException;
        }
        return localOracleConnection;
      }

      protected oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling()
      {
        return this.physicalConnection;
      }

      private static final String _Copyright_2007_Oracle_All_Rights_Reserved_ = null;
      public static final boolean TRACE = false;
    }
```

BLOB.java

```
    package oracle.sql;

    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.io.Reader;
    import java.sql.Blob;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import oracle.jdbc.LargeObjectAccessMode;
    import oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError;
    import oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleBlob;

    public class BLOB extends DatumWithConnection implements OracleBlob {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2160152488501369185L;

        public static final int MAX_CHUNK_SIZE = 32768;
        public static final int DURATION_SESSION = 10;
        public static final int DURATION_CALL = 12;
        static final int OLD_WRONG_DURATION_SESSION = 1;
        static final int OLD_WRONG_DURATION_CALL = 2;
        public static final int MODE_READONLY = 0;
        public static final int MODE_READWRITE = 1;
        BlobDBAccess dbaccess;
        int dbChunkSize;
        boolean isFree;
        boolean fromObject;
        private long cachedLobLength;
        private byte[] prefetchData;
        private int prefetchDataSize;
        private boolean activePrefetch;
        static final int KDLCTLSIZE = 16;
        static final int KDF_FLAG = 88;
        static final int KDLIDDAT = 8;
        private static final String _Copyright_2007_Oracle_All_Rights_Reserved_ = null;
        public static final boolean TRACE = false;
        public static Object localObject;


        protected BLOB() {
            this.dbChunkSize = -1;
            this.isFree = false;

            this.fromObject = false;

            this.cachedLobLength = -1L;

            this.prefetchDataSize = 0;
            this.activePrefetch = false;
        }

        public BLOB(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection paramOracleConnection) throws SQLException {
            this(paramOracleConnection, null);
        }

        public BLOB(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection paramOracleConnection, byte[] paramArrayOfByte, boolean paramBoolean)
                throws SQLException {
            this(paramOracleConnection, paramArrayOfByte);

            this.fromObject = paramBoolean;
        }

        public BLOB(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection paramOracleConnection, byte[] paramArrayOfByte) throws SQLException {
            super(paramArrayOfByte);

            this.dbChunkSize = -1;
            this.isFree = false;

            this.fromObject = false;

            this.cachedLobLength = -1L;

            this.prefetchDataSize = 0;
            this.activePrefetch = false;

            assertNotNull(paramOracleConnection);
            setPhysicalConnectionOf(paramOracleConnection);

            this.dbaccess = getPhysicalConnection().createBlobDBAccess();

            this.dbaccess.incrementTempLobReferenceCount(paramArrayOfByte);
        }

        public long length() throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            long l = -1L;

            if ((this.activePrefetch) && (this.cachedLobLength != -1L))
                l = this.cachedLobLength;
            else if (canReadBasicLobDataInLocator())
                l = dilLength();
            else
                l = getDBAccess().length(this);
            return l;
        }

        public byte[] getBytes(long paramLong, int paramInt) throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                localObject = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 192);
                ((SQLException) localObject).fillInStackTrace();
                throw ((SQLException) localObject);
            }
            if ((paramInt < 0) || (paramLong < 1L)) {
                localObject = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 68, "getBytes()");
                ((SQLException) localObject).fillInStackTrace();
                throw ((SQLException) localObject);
            }

            if (canReadBasicLobDataInLocator()) {
                return dilGetBytes(paramLong, paramInt);
            }

            Object localObject = null;

            if (paramInt == 0) {
                return new byte[0];
            }
            if ((this.activePrefetch) && (((this.cachedLobLength == 0L)
                    || ((this.cachedLobLength > 0L) && (paramLong - 1L >= this.cachedLobLength))))) {
                localObject = null;
            } else {
                long l = 0L;
                byte[] arrayOfByte;
                if ((this.activePrefetch) && (this.cachedLobLength != -1L))
                    arrayOfByte = new byte[Math.min((int) this.cachedLobLength, paramInt)];
                else {
                    arrayOfByte = new byte[paramInt];
                }

                l = getBytes(paramLong, paramInt, arrayOfByte);

                if (l > 0L) {
                    if (l == paramInt) {
                        localObject = arrayOfByte;
                    } else {
                        localObject = new byte[(int) l];

                        System.arraycopy(arrayOfByte, 0, localObject, 0, (int) l);
                    }
                }
            }

            return ((byte[])localObject);
        }

        public InputStream getBinaryStream() throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            if (canReadBasicLobDataInLocator()) {
                return dilGetBinaryStream(1L);
            }
            return getDBAccess().newInputStream(this, getBufferSize(), 0L);
        }

        public long position(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, long paramLong) throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            return getDBAccess().position(this, paramArrayOfByte, paramLong);
        }

        public long position(Blob paramBlob, long paramLong) throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            return getDBAccess().position(this, (BLOB) paramBlob, paramLong);
        }

        public int getBytes(long paramLong, int paramInt, byte[] paramArrayOfByte) throws SQLException {
            SQLException localSQLException;
            if (this.isFree) {
                localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            if ((paramInt < 0) || (paramLong < 0L)) {
                localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 68,
                        "getBytes()");
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }

            if (paramArrayOfByte.length < paramInt) {
                paramInt = paramArrayOfByte.length;
            }
            return getDBAccess().getBytes(this, paramLong, paramInt, paramArrayOfByte);
        }

        public int putBytes(long paramLong, byte[] paramArrayOfByte) throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            return setBytes(paramLong, paramArrayOfByte);
        }

        public int putBytes(long paramLong, byte[] paramArrayOfByte, int paramInt) throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            return setBytes(paramLong, paramArrayOfByte, 0, paramInt);
        }

        public OutputStream getBinaryOutputStream() throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            return setBinaryStream(1L);
        }

        public byte[] getLocator() {
            return getBytes();
        }

        public void setLocator(byte[] paramArrayOfByte) {
            setBytes(paramArrayOfByte);
        }

        public int getChunkSize() throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            if (this.dbChunkSize <= 0) {
                this.dbChunkSize = getDBAccess().getChunkSize(this);
            }

            return this.dbChunkSize;
        }

        public int getBufferSize() throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            int i = getChunkSize();
            int j = i;

            if ((i >= 32768) || (i <= 0)) {
                j = 32768;
            } else {
                j = 32768 / i * i;
            }

            return j;
        }

        public static BLOB empty_lob() throws SQLException {
            return getEmptyBLOB();
        }

        public static BLOB getEmptyBLOB() throws SQLException {
            byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[86];

            arrayOfByte[1] = 84;
            arrayOfByte[5] = 24;

            BLOB localBLOB = new BLOB();

            localBLOB.setShareBytes(arrayOfByte);

            return localBLOB;
        }

        public boolean isEmptyLob() throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            boolean bool = (shareBytes()[5] & 0x10) != 0;

            return bool;
        }

        public boolean isSecureFile() throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            boolean bool = (shareBytes()[7] & 0xFFFFFF80) != 0;
            return bool;
        }

        public OutputStream getBinaryOutputStream(long paramLong) throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            return getDBAccess().newOutputStream(this, getBufferSize(), paramLong, false);
        }

        public InputStream getBinaryStream(long paramLong) throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            if (canReadBasicLobDataInLocator()) {
                return dilGetBinaryStream(paramLong);
            }
            return getDBAccess().newInputStream(this, getBufferSize(), paramLong);
        }

        public void trim(long paramLong) throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            truncate(paramLong);
        }

        public static BLOB createTemporary(Connection paramConnection, boolean paramBoolean, int paramInt)
                throws SQLException {
            int i = paramInt;

            if (paramInt == 1) {
                i = 10;
            }
            if (paramInt == 2) {
                i = 12;
            }
            if ((paramConnection == null) || ((i != 10) && (i != 12))) {
                localObject = DatabaseError.createSqlException(null, 68,
                        "'conn' should not be null and 'duration' should either be equal to DURATION_SESSION or to DURATION_CALL");

                ((SQLException) localObject).fillInStackTrace();
                throw ((SQLException) localObject);
            }

            Object localObject = ((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) paramConnection).physicalConnectionWithin();

            return ((BLOB) getDBAccess((Connection) localObject).createTemporaryBlob((Connection) localObject, paramBoolean,
                    i));
        }

        public static void freeTemporary(BLOB paramBLOB) throws SQLException {
            if (paramBLOB == null) {
                return;
            }
            paramBLOB.freeTemporary();
        }

        public static boolean isTemporary(BLOB paramBLOB) throws SQLException {
            if (paramBLOB == null) {
                return false;
            }
            return paramBLOB.isTemporary();
        }

        public void freeTemporary() throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }

            int i = getDBAccess().decrementTempLobReferenceCount(shareBytes());

            if (i == 0)
                getDBAccess().freeTemporary(this, this.fromObject);
        }

        public boolean isTemporary() throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            return getDBAccess().isTemporary(this);
        }

        public void open(LargeObjectAccessMode paramLargeObjectAccessMode) throws SQLException {
            open(paramLargeObjectAccessMode.getCode());
        }

        public void open(int paramInt) throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            getDBAccess().open(this, paramInt);
        }

        public void close() throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            getDBAccess().close(this);
        }

        public boolean isOpen() throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            return getDBAccess().isOpen(this);
        }

        public int setBytes(long paramLong, byte[] paramArrayOfByte) throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }

            return getDBAccess().putBytes(this, paramLong, paramArrayOfByte, 0,
                    (paramArrayOfByte != null) ? paramArrayOfByte.length : 0);
        }

        public int setBytes(long paramLong, byte[] paramArrayOfByte, int paramInt1, int paramInt2) throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            return getDBAccess().putBytes(this, paramLong, paramArrayOfByte, paramInt1, paramInt2);
        }

        public OutputStream setBinaryStream(long paramLong) throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            return getDBAccess().newOutputStream(this, getBufferSize(), paramLong, true);
        }

        public void truncate(long paramLong) throws SQLException {
            SQLException localSQLException;
            if (this.isFree) {
                localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            if (paramLong < 0L) {
                localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 68,
                        "'len' should be >= 0. ");
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }

            getDBAccess().trim(this, paramLong);
        }

        public Object toJdbc() throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            return this;
        }

        public boolean isConvertibleTo(Class paramClass) {
            String str = paramClass.getName();

            return ((str.compareTo("java.io.InputStream") == 0) || (str.compareTo("java.io.Reader") == 0));
        }

        public Reader characterStreamValue() throws SQLException {
            getInternalConnection();
            return getDBAccess().newConversionReader(this, 8);
        }

        public InputStream asciiStreamValue() throws SQLException {
            getInternalConnection();
            return getDBAccess().newConversionInputStream(this, 2);
        }

        public InputStream binaryStreamValue() throws SQLException {
            return getBinaryStream();
        }

        public Object makeJdbcArray(int paramInt) {
            return new BLOB[paramInt];
        }

        public BlobDBAccess getDBAccess() throws SQLException {
            SQLException localSQLException;
            if (this.dbaccess == null) {
                if (isEmptyLob()) {
                    localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 98);
                    localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                    throw localSQLException;
                }

                this.dbaccess = getInternalConnection().createBlobDBAccess();
            }

            if (getPhysicalConnection().isClosed()) {
                localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 8);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }

            return this.dbaccess;
        }

        public static BlobDBAccess getDBAccess(Connection paramConnection) throws SQLException {
            return ((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) paramConnection).physicalConnectionWithin().createBlobDBAccess();
        }

        public Connection getJavaSqlConnection() throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException;
            }
            return super.getJavaSqlConnection();
        }

        public final void setLength(long paramLong) {
            this.cachedLobLength = paramLong;
        }

        public final void setChunkSize(int paramInt) {
            this.dbChunkSize = paramInt;
        }

        public final void setPrefetchedData(byte[] paramArrayOfByte) {
            if (paramArrayOfByte == null)
                setPrefetchedData(null, 0);
            else
                setPrefetchedData(paramArrayOfByte, paramArrayOfByte.length);
        }

        public final void setPrefetchedData(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, int paramInt) {
            this.prefetchData = paramArrayOfByte;
            this.prefetchDataSize = paramInt;
        }

        public final byte[] getPrefetchedData() {
            return this.prefetchData;
        }

        public final int getPrefetchedDataSize() {
            return this.prefetchDataSize;
        }

        public final void setActivePrefetch(boolean paramBoolean) {
            if ((this.activePrefetch) && (!(paramBoolean)))
                clearCachedData();
            this.activePrefetch = paramBoolean;
        }

        public final void clearCachedData() {
            this.cachedLobLength = -1L;
            this.prefetchData = null;
        }

        public final boolean isActivePrefetch() {
            return this.activePrefetch;
        }

        boolean canReadBasicLobDataInLocator() throws SQLException {
            byte[] arrayOfByte = shareBytes();
            if ((arrayOfByte == null) || (arrayOfByte.length < 102)) {
              return false;
            }
            if (!getPhysicalConnection().isDataInLocatorEnabled()) {
              return false;
            }
            int i = arrayOfByte[6] & 0xFF;
            int j = arrayOfByte[7] & 0xFF;
            int k = (i & 0x8) == 8 ? 1 : 0;
            int m = (j & 0xFFFFFF80) == -128 ? 1 : 0;
            int n = 0;
            if ((k != 0) && (m == 0))
            {
              n = ((arrayOfByte[88] & 0xFF) & 0x8) == 8 ? 1 : 0;
            }
            return (k != 0) && (m == 0) && (n != 0);
        }

        int dilLength() {
            return (shareBytes().length - 86 - 16);
        }

        byte[] dilGetBytes(long paramLong, int paramInt) throws SQLException {
            if (paramInt == 0) {
                return new byte[0];
            }

            if (dilLength() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            int i = (int) Math.min(paramInt, dilLength() - (paramLong - 1L));

            if (i <= 0) {
                return null;
            }

            byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[i];
            System.arraycopy(shareBytes(), (int) (paramLong - 1L) + 86 + 16, arrayOfByte, 0, i);
            return arrayOfByte;
        }

        InputStream dilGetBinaryStream(long paramLong) throws SQLException {
            if (paramLong < 0L) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Arguments");
            }

            byte[] arrayOfByte = dilGetBytes(paramLong, dilLength());

            if (arrayOfByte == null) {
                arrayOfByte = new byte[0];
            }

            return new ByteArrayInputStream(arrayOfByte);
        }

        public void free() throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree)
                return;
            if (isOpen())
                close();
            if (isTemporary())
                freeTemporary();
            this.isFree = true;
            this.dbaccess = null;
        }

        public InputStream getBinaryStream(long paramLong1, long paramLong2) throws SQLException {
            if (this.isFree) {
                SQLException localSQLException1 = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        192);
                localSQLException1.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException1;
            }
            if (canReadBasicLobDataInLocator()) {
                return dilGetBinaryStream(paramLong1, paramLong2);
            }
            long l = length();
            if ((paramLong1 < 1L) || (paramLong2 < 0L) || (paramLong1 > l) || (paramLong1 - 1L + paramLong2 > l)) {
                SQLException localSQLException2 = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(),
                        68);
                localSQLException2.fillInStackTrace();
                throw localSQLException2;
            }
            return getDBAccess().newInputStream(this, getChunkSize(), paramLong1, paramLong2);
        }

        InputStream dilGetBinaryStream(long paramLong1, long paramLong2) throws SQLException {
            int i = dilLength();
            if ((paramLong1 < 1L) || (paramLong2 < 0L) || (paramLong1 > i) || (paramLong1 - 1L + paramLong2 > i)) {
                localObject = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 68);
                ((SQLException) localObject).fillInStackTrace();
                throw ((SQLException) localObject);
            }
            byte[] localObject = dilGetBytes(paramLong1, i - (int) (paramLong1 - 1L));
            return ((InputStream) new ByteArrayInputStream(localObject, 0, (int) paramLong2));
        }
    }
```