# Maven is picking dependency of old version

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to integrate Maven - Spring MVC - Rest , but i am facing issue in which maven is not picking "spring-web/aop/beans/context/core"(version 4.3.12) dependency .

Instead of spring-web/aop/beans/context/core  4.3.12.RELEASE , maven is picking "spring-web/aop/beans/context/core" 2.5.6.SEC03 dependency. because of this "org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;" is not getting resolve as it is not there in spring web 2.5.6.SEC03

Maven Version ->  apache-maven-3.5.2

[image: Maven Version]

Maven env variables
[image: Maven env variables]

[image: Intellij Maven Dependency]

[image: Maven Respository Screenshot]

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.portal</groupId>
    <artifactId>HumanResourcePortal</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</warName>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>
                                /home/shivam/apache-tomcat-7.0.81/webapps/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}
                            </directory>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>
                                /home/shivam/apache-tomcat-7.0.81/webapps
                            </directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>
                                    ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.{packaging}
                                </include>
                            </includes>
                       </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>/home/shivam/apache-tomcat-7.0.81/webapps</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${packaging}</include>
                                        <include>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

after Running maven dependency tree

[image: after Running maven dependency tree]

after running "mvn help:effectivePom"
[image: mvn help:effectivePom]

Comment: What does `mvn help:effectivePom` look like?

Comment: @Makoto , Added the output of mvn help:effectivePom

Comment: It should be `effective-pom`, not `effectivePom`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably, that outdated Spring version comes from `jersey-spring` transient dependencies. Try to use one of the latest versions.

Better options?

Well, first of all, you can use [`<dependencyManagement>`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) section. It is used to lock the versions of the dependencies across the project. `<dependencyManagement>` will work with any artifacts.

Second, starting somewhere from 3.x releases [Spring provides a Bill of Materials](https://medium.com/@gaurav.agrawal/maven-bill-of-materials-dependency-b6eb88f5c188). BOM is a special concept in Maven, like a `<dependencyManagement>`, but it allows to lock multiple dependencies with one BOM import. BOMs are prepared and published for some popular libraries, like Spring or Camel.

Comment: yeah that is because of jersey spring 1.8 . now i removed that dependency .

Comment: can you please suggest me which version of jersey spring should i use. as on "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-spring" latest version is 1.9  and if i uses that then it again start picking spring jars with version 3.0.0.RC3

Comment: Latest version of Jersey is actually `1.19.4`: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.19.4. I am not sure which Spring version it depends on. Just force a version you need with `dependencyManagement` and pray that Jersey will work with it :)

Comment: ohh sorry.didn't notice 1.19.4 ..i was thinking it  1.1.9.4

Comment: on using spring-jersey 1.19 jar again it is picking spring -jar 3.0.0.RC3.

Comment: which is giving this error "nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory"

Comment: as this class is not present  spring-context 3.0.0.RC3 but is it there in spring-context latest 4.3.12

Comment: Use `dependencyManagement` and force versions of Spring Framework!

Answer (score 4):

Choosing dependency version that is closer to project root a known behavior of Maven dependency lookup. Let's imagine that you have the following dependency tree:

```
Your Project
- library-A-1.0.jar
-- library-B-1.5.jar (dependency of library-A)
- library-B-1.2.jar
```

The library set that maven will pick for you will be `library-A-1.0.jar` and `library-B-1.2.jar` (as this version is closer to project root at distance 1 compared to `library-B-1.5.jar` at disatnce 2).

The usual approach to resolve this kind of issues is to

1. Analyze your dependency tree with [Maven Dependency Plug-in](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)
2. Either define required library version closer to project root
3. Or exclude unwanted dependency in included artifact
4. Or move dependency higher in pom.xml file when at the same distance (first one will be used)

Comment: added the output of maven dependency tree plugin. but is is also failing

Comment: now i am able to run maven dependency tree successfully. that is because of jersey spring 1.8 . now i removed that dependency and 
now it is loading sping jar 4.3.12. "But it in unable to locate oracle ojdbc jars." can you please tell me which one i should use ? ojdbc6 or ojdbc14 ... and what is the difference among them

Comment: can you please suggest me which version of jersey spring should i use. as on "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-spring" latest version is 1.9 and if i uses that then it again start picking spring jars with version 3.0.0.RC3

Comment: @shivam, it may look like `ojdbc14` is newer version of `ojdbc6` and you should use it, but it's not! Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3212160/750510), which explains crazy Oracle namings. And use `ojdbc6`.