# ojdbc14 external jar file raises not found exception

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to add external jar file in my spring boot project.

In `pom.xml` I have:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ojdbc14</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>C:\Users\myUser\Dropbox\Projects\myProject\ojdbc14.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In a class in a java file I have:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

When I run the project I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at com.ucy.MyApi.getdbConnection(myApi.java:23)
```

Comment: Are you really still using Java 1.4?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, but a system that we are connecting unfortunately yes and I have to connect with it.

Comment: JDBC drivers are generally backwards compatible, so you can use a newer driver to connect to an older database.

Comment: The `system` scope is similar to `provided`, meaning that the jar will be provided by something (usually the container) during runtime, but will be available for compile-time from a system path. So you're using the wrong scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help [ojdbc14.jar vs. ojdbc6.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209647/ojdbc14-jar-vs-ojdbc6-jar)

Are you sure that's the correct definition in the POM?

I use this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>18.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Check for the specific version of Oracle and the proper jar version. It should not need the system path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a maven command to install a 3rd party jars:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\myUser\Dropbox\Projects\myProject\ojdbc14.jar -DgroupId=ojdbc14 -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

after that change your pom file like following:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>ojdbc14</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```